# C++. Как показать все сообщения на аккаунте mail?

Tags: c++

Всем здравствуйте. Мне нужно сделать программу, которая показывает все входящие  сообщения на аккаунте gmail. Если точно: мне нужно узнать, от кого пришло сообщение, какой заголовок и какой текст. Лучше всего - показать от кого пришло сообщение.
Не важно, будь то C++ Builder, C++ Native или Visual C++.
Мне нужно именно узнать как это сделать, и, желательно, пример кода, спасибо.

Comment: Если именно gmail, то у них есть api. Иначе imap/pop.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно пример с кодом или ссылку на библиотеку?

Comment: Неа, я не знаю.

Comment: У gmail какая-то фишка с контролем. Линуксоиды не могут взять почту. Только вручную через web. С виндой не дружу... https://9to5google.com/2019/12/16/google-blocking-obscure-browsers-gmail/

Comment: curl + поискать в интернете как с ним работать с протоколом imap.